Mysql query is too slow for what it is, help me debug it
I have the following query which takes about 5 seconds to complete, it used to be 0.5s, then 1s, 2s now we are at 5s despite the fact that the amount of data in database has not changed! This query makes a select to get a portion of data to process and update some columns (no new rows are added), normally it has a "limit 500" but query time with "limit 1" and "limit 500" is the same, so for the simplicity I changed this post to "limit 1".
I made a copy of production table on the same server to be able to run various tests and changes without hurting the production data, also some data was obfuscated but all the queries and their outputs are real
The table “test” has 34 million rows and 11.3GB size of which index is 3.3GB. The server is Freebsd 13.2, mysql 8.0.35 on pretty decent Samsung nvme drive, 64GB ram and innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 42G. Server is not swapping and has nearly 4GB free memory. There is quite a bit of disk IO load coming from queries to other databases hosted on the same server (and probably mostly binary log because this is replication master), however if I disable all other queries and run only the query in question the execution time is exactly the same.
The slow query:
SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit 1;
+--------------+---------------+
| t_channel_id | login         |
+--------------+---------------+
| 933271419    | sunday1funday |
+--------------+---------------+
1 row in set (4.43 sec)

Index is properly used and covers all WHERE columns,
If I remove column videos_scanned_lock from the query the time is 0.35s (still slow but much faster)
if I remove ONLY column t_channel_id from the query time is 0s
I have a theory why the time was much faster at the beginning and now its around 5s. We are now processing records around 30th million row (out of 34) and in the beginning the selected rows were from a beginning of the table and now like “almost the whole table has to be scanned first in order to get to the results”. But is 34 million records a lot for mysql? I suppose not, the whole table is less than 1/4th of innodb buffer size. As a proof of this theory, in previous paragraph I wrote that if I remove column t_channel_id from the query, time is 0s – this is because if I remove this column there are shown results from the beginning of the table. Second proof, is that the query gives certain result, if I change value of t_channel_id for this result into a much smaller number the query time will be much shorter (because with lower ID it will be found earlier). I am pretty sure I answered my own question BUT why this is happening? I believe something must be misconfigured but I cannot find what it is and I hope to find an answer here. Any tips to improve this situation are appreciated :)
Below I provide debug data: show create table, profiler, describe analyze and my.cnf
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `channel_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_channel_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `videos_scanned` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `videos_scanned_lock` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`),
  KEY `t_channel_id_2` (`t_channel_id`,`videos_scanned`,`videos_scanned_lock`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34626837 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin

describe SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | NULL       | range | t_channel_id_2 | t_channel_id_2 | 1023    | NULL | 16992061 |     1.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------+

describe analyze SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit
1;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXPLAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=7.65e+6 rows=1) (actual time=4407..4407 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Index range scan on test using t_channel_id_2 over (NULL < t_channel_id), with index condition: ((test.videos_scanned_lock = 0) and (test.t_channel_id is not null) and (test.videos_scanned is null))  (cost=7.65e+6 rows=17e+6) (actual time=4407..4407 rows=1 loops=1)
 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (4.41 sec)

SET profiling = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit 1;
+--------------+---------------+
| t_channel_id | login         |
+--------------+---------------+
| 933271419    | sunday1funday |
+--------------+---------------+
1 row in set (4.43 sec)

show profile cpu;
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
| Status                         | Duration | CPU_user | CPU_system |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
| starting                       | 0.000142 | 0.000372 |   0.000036 |
| Executing hook on transaction  | 0.000063 | 0.000048 |   0.000004 |
| starting                       | 0.000027 | 0.000022 |   0.000002 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000028 | 0.000025 |   0.000003 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000018 | 0.000016 |   0.000001 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000098 | 0.000094 |   0.000009 |
| init                           | 0.000025 | 0.000019 |   0.000002 |
| System lock                    | 0.000026 | 0.000024 |   0.000002 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000091 | 0.000084 |   0.000008 |
| statistics                     | 0.000284 | 0.000269 |   0.000026 |
| preparing                      | 0.000126 | 0.000119 |   0.000011 |
| executing                      | 4.426675 | 6.156588 |   0.156978 |
| end                            | 0.000016 | 0.000005 |   0.000001 |
| query end                      | 0.000004 | 0.000003 |   0.000000 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000005 | 0.000005 |   0.000001 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000006 | 0.000006 |   0.000000 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000010 | 0.000014 |   0.000002 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000027 | 0.000020 |   0.000001 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000008 | 0.000007 |   0.000001 |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
19 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

[mysqld]
user                            = mysql
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /tmp/mysql.sock
bind-address                    = 0.0.0.0
datadir                         = /var/db/mysql
log-output                      = FILE
relay-log-recovery              = 1
slow-query-log                  = 1
server-id                       = 29
sync_binlog                     = 1
sync_relay_log                  = 1
binlog_cache_size               = 16M
binlog_expire_logs_seconds      = 43200
default_password_lifetime       = 0
enforce-gtid-consistency        = 1
gtid-mode                       = On
safe-user-create                = 1
lower_case_table_names          = 1
explicit-defaults-for-timestamp = 1
myisam-recover-options          = BACKUP,FORCE
table_open_cache                = 16384
table_definition_cache          = 8192
net_retry_count                 = 16384
key_buffer_size                 = 256M
max_allowed_packet              = 64M
long_query_time                 = 0.2
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 42G
innodb_data_home_dir            = /var/db/mysql
innodb_log_group_home_dir       = /var/db/mysql
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:128M:autoextend
innodb_temp_data_file_path      = ibtmp1:128M:autoextend
innodb_flush_method             = O_DSYNC
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 32M
innodb_write_io_threads         = 12
innodb_read_io_threads          = 12
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 2
innodb_redo_log_capacity        = 8192M
log_error                       = /var/db/mysql/mysql-error.log
slow_query_log_file             = /var/db/mysql/mysql-slow.log
skip_name_resolve
mysqlx                          = 0
tls_version                     = TLSv1.2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
replica_parallel_workers        = 1
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay  = 10000

Edit for Ergest:
...
KEY `channel_id` (`videos_scanned_lock`,`channel_id`,`t_channel_id`) USING BTREE

SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test force index (channel_id) WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit 1;
+--------------+----------------+
| t_channel_id | login          |
+--------------+----------------+
| 921437844    | marryme2       |
+--------------+----------------+
1 row in set (50.80 sec)

describe SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test force index (channel_id) WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | NULL       | ref  | channel_id    | channel_id | 4       | const | 68378 |     9.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

describe format=json SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test force index (channel_id) WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit 1;
....
 {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "2094461.53"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "test",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
        "t_channel_id_2",
        "channel_id"
      ],
      "key": "channel_id",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "videos_scanned_lock"
      ],
      "key_length": "4",
      "ref": [
        "const"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 16992061,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 1529285,
      "filtered": "9.00",
      "index_condition": "(`db`.`test`.`t_channel_id` is not null)",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "395255.43",
        "eval_cost": "152928.54",
        "prefix_cost": "2094461.53",
        "data_read_per_join": "4G"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "t_channel_id",
        "login",
        "videos_scanned",
        "videos_scanned_lock"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "(`db`.`test`.`videos_scanned` is null)"
    }
  }
} |

For @Rick James
it simply does not work
show create table test;
....
KEY `t_channel_id` (`t_channel_id`,`login`,`videos_scanned`,`videos_scanned_lock`)

SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test force index (t_channel_id) WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_loc
k=0 limit 1;
+--------------+----------------+
| t_channel_id | login          |
+--------------+----------------+
| 921437844    | blahblahcar |
+--------------+----------------+
1 row in set (9.99 sec)

describe SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test force index (t_channel_id) WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | NULL       | range | t_channel_id  | t_channel_id | 1023    | NULL | 16992061 |     0.02 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+

explain format=json SELECT t_channel_id,login FROM test force index (t_channel_id) WHERE t_channel_id IS NOT NULL AND videos_scanned IS NULL AND videos_scanned_lock=0 limit 1;
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "4712106.82"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "test",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "t_channel_id"
      ],
      "key": "t_channel_id",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "t_channel_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "1023",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 16992061,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 3906,
      "filtered": "0.02",
      "using_index": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "4711716.19",
        "eval_cost": "390.62",
        "prefix_cost": "4712106.82",
        "data_read_per_join": "11M"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "t_channel_id",
        "login",
        "videos_scanned",
        "videos_scanned_lock"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`db`.`test`.`videos_scanned_lock` = 0) and (`db`.`test`.`t_channel_id` is not null) and (`db`.`test`.`videos_scanned` is null))"
    }
  }


i would change the order of the index and put videos_scanned_lock at the start and try it again

@nbk I did change order of index columns placing videos_scanned_lock and the query time was the same. Then I changed order in the WHERE clause placing videos_scanned_lock=0 first but the query time is still the same (not sure if order in WHERE is important)

@Ergest Basha after doing the changes you mentioned the query time is 0.01s however there is also something strange happenign which I do not understand yet. Although the result is correct (show results matching the query) it is completely different than results using the previous index. Using new index the result comes from the beginning of the table and this is probably why the query is so fast. I am still investigating this however how is this even possible? (I have a theory but difficult to write about it) Also why is the index you suggested missing one of the WHERE columns?

@ratatata what do you mean the index is missing one column? That is not a strange result , but the expected one. Without an order the results are not defined and might be different every time you run the query. By the way 0.01 is acceptable ?

@Ergest Basha 0.01 would be perfect but the few results with low channel_id (so coming from beginning of the table) were already parsed and now there are only high number channel_id results remaining and the slow query is back, actually worse than before :) I updated original question with the new data you asked for. I need to use force index because I left the previous index in place and actually sometimes I am not sure which index mysql uses, so I want to be sure the new index is used

"the result is [...] completely different" -- since you don't specify the order of the result set (by using order by), the database engine is free to return any row that matches the criteria, which is exactly what happens.

@Ergest Basha you altered column names, I believe it was a typo? I changed order to
videos_scanned_lock=0 and videos_scanned is null and t_channel_id is null (I believe this is what you meant)
and the time is 5s
here is global status: https://pastebin.com/tYHN8SUz
but whatever you can see, there I can stop all other queries to this server, restart it, and the query time will be the same (tested this earlier)

I just notice this small reply form does not format text properly, and I cannot edit my previous message anymore, sorry

The SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; is useless without SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  Please don't use \G; use simply ;.

@Rick James sorry I did not know, here is show global variables: https://pastebin.com/AeEhkGrP
and here is a new show global status: https://pastebin.com/Hxzk0SaU

PROFILE is rarely of any use.
This composite index should help
INDEX(videos_scanned, videos_scanned_lock, -- either order is OK
      t_channel_id, login)   -- to make the INDEX "covering" 

The short explanation (for your query):

Start the index with columns tested with =
then ranges tests (such as IS NOT NULL)
finally all other columns needed (to make it "covering").

Long explanation: see my Index Cookbook

it does not work, I updated original post with new data. Notice it uses where before index, that is a little strange

"does not work" -- got error?  aborts?  got wrong answer?  other?

@ratatata - Please provide EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON for when my index was used.

I updated my original post with explain format=json at the bottom. You wrote "either order is OK" - does it mean the order of columns in the index?

The columns in the index.  Also those 2 columns need to come before the other 2 in the index.

changing the index order to videos_scanned, videos_scanned_lock,  t_channel_id, login finally fixed it and the query time is 0. Can you tell me why this order is a proper one? Is it because first two columns are constantly changing while t_channel_id and login remains unchanged?

@ratatata - I added to my answer.  "Constantly changing" means "selective".  But even that is not the real answer, which would involve a dissertation on indexing.

(not much exciting here...)
Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:
 

Observations:

Version: 8.0.35
64 GB of RAM
Uptime = 4d 15:17:02
1.45e+3 QPS

The More Important Issues:
Suggest configuration changes:
innodb_io_capacity = 1000   -- if SSD
table_open_cache = 1000

innodb_log_files_size = 2G -- innodb_redo_log_capacity = 8G should be fine.
Look in SHOW ENGINE=INNODB STATUS for the 'latest deadlock'.
Details and other observations:
( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = (0 + 0 + 25119175 + 81458209 + 8195499 + 80652334) / 400622 = 487 /sec -- IOPs?
-- If the hardware can handle it, set innodb_io_capacity (now 200) to about this value.
( ( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) / innodb_io_capacity / Uptime ) = ( 0 + 0 + 25119175 + 81458209 + 8195499 + 80652334 ) / 200 / 400622 = 243.9% -- This may be a metric indicating what innodb_io_capacity is set reasonably.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the hardware can handle it.
( table_open_cache ) = 16,384 -- Number of table descriptors to cache
-- Several hundred is usually good.
( binlog_cache_size * max_connections ) = (16M * 151) / 65536M = 3.7% -- RAM used for caching transactions on the way to the binlog.
-- Decrease binlog_cache_size (now 16777216) and/or max_connections (now 151)
( innodb_buffer_pool_size / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 43008M / 8 = 5376MB -- Size of each buffer_pool instance.
-- An instance should be at least 1GB. In very large RAM, have 16 instances.
( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,024 * 4 = 4,096 -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 4). Also check for swapping.
( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024 -- innodb_lru_scan_depth is a very poorly named variable. A better name would be innodb_free_page_target_per_buffer_pool. It is a number of pages InnoDB tries to keep free in each buffer pool instance to speed up read and page creation operations.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth
( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200 -- When flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky. Use 2000 if using SSD drive.
( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10 -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)
( (Innodb_buffer_pool_reads + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed) ) = ((19069505 + 80652334) ) / 400622 = 248 /sec -- InnoDB I/O
( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = 80652334 / 400622 = 201 /sec -- Writes (flushes)
( Innodb_os_log_written ) = 417798258688 / 400622 = 1042873 /sec -- This is an indicator of how busy InnoDB is.
-- Very busy InnoDB.
( innodb_log_buffer_size / innodb_log_file_size ) = 32M / 48M = 66.7% -- Buffer is in RAM; file is on disk.
-- The buffer_size should be smaller and/or the file_size should be larger.
( Innodb_log_writes ) = 318280758 / 400622 = 794 /sec
( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 417,798,258,688 / (400622 / 3600) / 2 / 48M = 37.3 -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)
( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 400,622 / 60 * 48M / 417798258688 = 0.804 -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, innodb_log_file_size can be changed dynamically; I don't know about MariaDB. Be sure to also change my.cnf
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 50331648). (Cannot change in AWS.)
( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT
( Innodb_row_lock_time_max ) = 50,981 -- Max time to lock a row (millisec)
-- Possibly conflicting queries; possibly table scans.
( Innodb_row_lock_waits ) = 1993787 / 400622 = 5 /sec -- How often there is a delay in getting a row lock.
-- May be caused by complex queries that could be optimized.
( Innodb_dblwr_writes ) = 8195499 / 400622 = 20 /sec -- "Doublewrite buffer" writes to disk. "Doublewrites" are a reliability feature. Some newer versions / configurations don't need them.
-- (Symptom of other issues)
( ( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written ) / Uptime / innodb_io_capacity ) = ( 25119175 + 81458209 ) / 400622 / 200 = 133.0% -- If > 100%, need more io_capacity.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the drives can handle it.
( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200 -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor. Limits write IO requests per second (IOPS).
-- For starters: HDD: 200; SSD: 2000.
( innodb_adaptive_hash_index ) = innodb_adaptive_hash_index = ON -- Whether to use the adapative hash (AHI).
-- ON for mostly readonly; OFF for DDL-heavy
( Innodb_row_lock_current_waits ) = 590 -- The number of row locks currently being waited for by operations on InnoDB tables. Zero is pretty normal.
-- Something big is going on?
( innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ) = 0 -- 1 = secure; 2 = faster
-- (You decide) Use 1, along with sync_binlog (now 1)=1 for the greatest level of fault tolerance. 0 is best for speed. 2 is a compromise between 0 and 1.
( innodb_adaptive_hash_index ) = innodb_adaptive_hash_index = ON -- Usually should be ON.
-- There are cases where OFF is better. See also innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts (now 8) (after 5.7.9) and innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions (MariaDB and Percona). ON has been implicated in rare crashes (bug 73890). 10.5.0 decided to default OFF.
( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.
( bulk_insert_buffer_size ) = 8M / 65536M = 0.01% -- Buffer for multi-row INSERTs and LOAD DATA
-- Too small could hinder such operations.
( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (218991721 + 3627939 + 0 + 45 + 74927620 + 0) / 400622 = 742 /sec -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives
( log_slow_slave_statements ) = log_slow_slave_statements = OFF -- (5.6.11, 5.7.1) By default, replicated statements won't show up in the slowlog; this causes them to show.
-- It can be helpful in the slowlog to see writes that could be interfering with Replica reads.
( Aborted_connects / Connections ) = 20,179 / 54134 = 37.3% -- Perhaps a hacker is trying to break in? (Attempts to connect)
Abnormally small:
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs = 0
gtid_executed_compression_period = 0

Abnormally large:
Binlog_cache_use = 634 /sec
Com_alter_user = 0.009 /HR
Com_create_user = 0.018 /HR
Com_drop_user = 0.009 /HR
Com_insert = 546 /sec
Com_show_binlogs = 19 /HR
Com_show_engine_status = 0.032 /sec
Com_show_plugins = 19 /HR
Com_show_profile = 0.018 /HR
Com_show_slave_status = 0.032 /sec
Com_show_storage_engines = 0.57 /HR
Com_update = 187 /sec
Handler_commit/Questions = 136.6%
Handler_external_lock = 2897 /sec
Handler_prepare = 1268 /sec
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key = 138
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty = 273,400
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc = 125,178
Innodb_data_writes = 1024 /sec
Innodb_data_writes - Innodb_log_writes - Innodb_dblwr_writes = 209 /sec
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written = 201 /sec
Innodb_log_write_requests = 7289 /sec
Innodb_pages_created = 16 /sec
Innodb_pages_written = 203 /sec
Innodb_rows_inserted = 536 /sec
Innodb_system_rows_deleted = 9.9 /sec
Innodb_system_rows_inserted = 9.9 /sec
Innodb_system_rows_read = 5.24e+6
Innodb_system_rows_updated = 0.2 /sec
Ssl_accepts = 24,222
Ssl_finished_accepts = 24,221
binlog_cache_size = 1.68e+7
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay = 10,000
innodb_open_files = 16,384
max_error_count = 1,024
net_retry_count = 16,384
performance_schema_error_size = 5,307
performance_schema_max_cond_classes = 150
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes = 350
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes = 60
performance_schema_max_stage_classes = 175
performance_schema_max_statement_classes = 219
performance_schema_max_thread_classes = 100
slave_parallel_workers = 1
table_definition_cache = 8,192
table_open_cache / max_connections = 108

Abnormal strings:
character_set_system = utf8mb3
default_authentication_plugin = caching_sha2_password
enforce_gtid_consistency = ON
event_scheduler = ON
gtid_mode = ON
have_query_cache = NO
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/db/mysql
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:128M:autoextend
innodb_use_native_aio = OFF
lower_case_table_names = 1
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
protocol_compression_algorithms = zlib,zstd,uncompressed
relay_log_recovery = ON
slave_allow_batching = ON
slave_parallel_type = LOGICAL_CLOCK
slave_preserve_commit_order = ON
slave_rows_search_algorithms = INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN
sql_slave_skip_counter = 0
version_compile_machine = amd64
version_compile_zlib = 1.2.13


wow that is an insane analyze, thank you. I am going to read and apply all your hints, did you use any software to analyze that? Hard to believe you read  and processed it all by hand. The server is quite busy, however if I reboot it and disable all queries and all other clients, other than me doing this single query (the one about this post) from the console, and the server is doing absolutely nothing during this time, the time of the query will still be 5s. Are we looking into server optimizations to decrease that time because nothing can be done about the query/indexes itself?

I do not like changing so many settings blindy without understanding what is happening, I will need at least a day to analyze your entire post, however I included your suggested configuration changes
innodb_io_capacity = 1000
table_open_cache = 1000
innodb_log_files_size = 2G
restarted mysql and cut off all other clients, now its only me accessing the server and I checked right now there are no deadlocks, the server does absolutely nothing.  Once again the query takes 5 seconds :-) I am starting to think this cannot be rectified?

I also want to address some other concerns from your response, the server is not swapping, there is 20 gb free memory, nobody is trying to hack it, it is properly firewalled but why the disconnected clients I dont know yet, I will investigate, the server has a pretty decent samsung nvme ssd

innodb_log_file_size and innodb_log_files_in_group are deprecated in MySQL 8.0.30. These variables are superseded by innodb_redo_log_capacity.
I have innodb_redo_log_capacity set at 8GB, too much?

8G is probably a good size.

Can you please explain this? I thought in-memory is better than on-disk?
( innodb_log_buffer_size / innodb_log_file_size ) = 32M / 48M = 66.7% -- Buffer is in RAM; file is on disk. -- The buffer_size should be smaller and/or the file_size should be larger.

@ratatata - "0.804 Minutes between InnoDB log rotations" led me to suggesting increasing innodb_log_file_size from 48M to, say, 8G. The increase avoids having to stop to clean up the undo/redo file so often. The quotient indicates frequency of flushing to disk; Increasing the file size will stop my analysis from flagging the quotent.

When I set innodb_log_file_size  it shows a warning in log that the setting is being depreciated. Mysql docs at mysql.com says the same thing. I am using 8.0.35, what should I do?

I want to point out that my innodb_redo_log_capacity is set at 8GB, which according to my understanding of the docs replaces both innodb_log_file_size and innodb_log_files_in_group, am I right?

@ratatata - That sounds right.  My bad.
